# Turning a pfSense rooter into a Tor gateway?

Tags: firewall, privacy, freebsd, tor, pfsense

I've recently started experimenting with the [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) rooter/firewall and I found it quite cool with plenty of features. I then saw it supports addons, so an idea popped into my mind:

Would it be possible to create an addon for pfSense which will take all the traffic of a private network (sitting behind the pfSense rooter/firewall) and, instead of forwarding it to the internet directly, funnel it into the Tor network?

This would be supper cool (I believe), since it would force all PCs in the private network to use Tor, and not allow them to access the internet directly.

It might even help with setting up Tor services, by not requiring to setup Tor on each an every server behind the rooter. It will be one step further from Tails OS, by moving from OS-level privacy to network-level privacy!

So, my questions are:

1. Is this possible, as my gut tells me that it is?
2. Any idea where to start from? I guess (after Googling it a bit) that there is nothing doing this already, so: is there a guideline on how one can turn a normal FreeBSD installation (since pfSense is based on FreeBSD) into a Tails-like OS, that sends all network traffic through Tor?

All I found on the internet was on how to install Tor Browser on a FreeBSD OS, but this is not what I want. pfSense does not have a GUI interface at the OS level (no widows in the OS, only command line interface and a web administration interface), so there is no meaning in trying to install Tor Browser.

Comment: Your google-fu is inadequate. I'm getting lots of results under "pfsense tor gateway", e.g. https://turbofuture.com/computers/How-to-Set-Up-a-Tor-Proxy-Server-on-pfSense. Looks like you need to chain a few things together, e.g. Tor proxy -> Squid (convert proxy to gateway).

Comment: @Andy Ohh..., indeed. Sorry about that. It seems that I've only used the `gateway` term after I quit searching and started writing the question. I've also had a doubt whether I should call it `tor` or `onion router` or something else. And I have spent some considerable time searching things like `make FreeBSD work like Tails`. Apparently, this was not one of my brightest days... :(

Comment: Coming back to this, I now know that OpnSense, an alternative firewall to pfSense, has a Tor addon that seems to provide a lot of Tor-related features.